# how to access create js using javascript and make interactive

Tags: javascript, html

how to access create js text using javascript and make it interactive

// ansfields

```
this.ans2_txt = new cjs.Text("", "bold 35px TektonPro-Bold", "#FFFFFF");
this.ans2_txt.textAlign = "center";
this.ans2_txt.lineHeight = 37;
this.ans2_txt.lineWidth = 39;
this.ans2_txt.setTransform(411.1,357.9);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include what you are trying to achieve, and why your code doesn't produce the desired outcome. Please also take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages.

Comment: hai CJ Dennis thank you for reply,

Comment: i have included the entire code in description please check and reply

Comment: I'm guessing `cjs` is some sort of library you haven't specified. You still need to say what you're trying to achieve. In what way do you want it to be interactive? What currently happens when you run the code? How does it fall short? I probably won't be able to answer your question myself. I'm here to help you improve it so that other people will understand the problem you are trying to solve.